# Probability of drawing balls without replacement in first and last draw

Tags: probability

If there are two red, three blue and four green balls in a bag and if three balls are drawn successively without replacement then probability of getting first draw as blue ball and third draw as red ball is what?

I did $P(\text{BRR})+P(\text{BBR})+P(\text{BGR})=\frac{42}{504}$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am getting the answer as 42/504, but the options dont mention that.

Comment: P(BRR)+P(BBR)+P(BGR)=42/504

Comment: Thanks. Reconfirmed the answer.

Comment: It's generally better if you post the steps you took too and also if you type up the post too. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Was one of the options $1/12$?

Comment: No. They were 0.05, 0.0713, 0.06667, 0.0644

Comment: Oh, they were given in decimal form?  How odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the first draw is blue is $1/3$.

Drawing from what's left, the probability that the next two balls are red is $(2/8)(1/7) = 1/28$.

Drawing from what's left, the probability that the second ball is not red, but the third ball is, is $(6/8)(2/7) = 3/14$.

So the overall probability is

$$P = \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{12}.$$

Comment: How is probability of first draw as blue 1/4? Shouldn't it be 3/9?

Comment: Dang it, I can't add.  O_o  Fixing now.

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry about that!

Comment: Oh, and by the way, that's the same answer you got, just in lowest terms! :)